# How to count no.of textboxes in HTML page and store it in html tag ,so that it can be used in another Servlet page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to count no. of textboxes in html page and use it in another servlet page that is given as action of form tag in html.

Answer (score 0):

You can get length using `getElementsByTagName`

```
var count = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').length;

save it in your form filed.
```

Comment: How do I use it in my Servlet page ,the lenght that is counted here?

Comment: You have to pass this count to that page. either by form or by url

Comment: That is only my question ,How can I pass a javascript variable to servlet page?

Comment: if you have link on your current page which take user to your servlet age add "?count="+count at end of url;. You need to share more information regarding navigation from one page to other.

Comment: Can I pass javascript variable like this?

Comment: I am navigating through action tag to the Servlet.